# Weird Behavior of ListView.builder and working with its index

Tags: flutter, dart, listview

I am using a `ListView.builder` along with StreamBuilder for getting user messages from Firebase. I have implemented my own login for Date separation of chats. through which I generate a custom date message between chats so that chats of different dates have clear separation. but strangely I came to this behaviour of list view:

I guess it is because As Listview reuses the widgets and I used index based logic in my code for generating dates message.
Please suggest me another approach for showing dates and separate chats like whatsapp if this issue is impossible to solve

Here is the code :

```
    StreamBuilder(
          stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection('chat')
              .orderBy(
                'createdAt',
                descending: true,
              ) //by default it is in accending order.
              .snapshots(), //with ordering by timestamps!
          builder: (ctx, chatSnapshot) {
            if (chatSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return Center(
                child: AdaptiveCircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }
    
            final chatDocs = chatSnapshot.data.docs;
            // print('CHATS_DATA : ${chatDocs.data()}');
            for (int i = 0; i < chatDocs.length; i++) {
              print(
                  'data for index : $i\n\t on ${getDateStr(chatDocs[i].data()['createdAt'])} ${chatDocs[i].data()['username']} : ${chatDocs[i].data()['text']}');
            }
            return ListView.builder(
              // addSemanticIndexes: false,
              // addAutomaticKeepAlives: false,
              // addRepaintBoundaries: false,
              // cacheExtent: 10,
              reverse: true,
              itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
                var putMessage;
                bool putDate = false;
                String currentDate;
                var nextDate;
                if (index == 0) {
                  datesMessage = getDateStr(chatDocs[index].data()['createdAt']);
    
                  currentDate = datesMessage;
                } else {
                  currentDate = getDateStr(chatDocs[index].data()['createdAt']);
                }
                if (index != chatDocs.length - 1)
                  nextDate = getDateStr(chatDocs[index + 1].data()['createdAt']);
    
                // print('for $index : $datesMessage $currentDate');
                bool loadNew = (index == chatDocs.length - 1) ||
                    (index != chatDocs.length - 1 &&
                        chatDocs[index + 1].data()['userId'] !=
                            chatDocs[index].data()['userId']) ||
                    (currentDate != nextDate);
    
                if (index != 0 && datesMessage != currentDate) {
                  putMessage = datesMessage;
                  datesMessage = currentDate;
                  putDate = true;
                  print('date changed.');
                } else {
                  putDate = false;
                }
    
                return Column(
                  children: [
                    // if (index == chatDocs.length - 1) Text(currentDate),
                    if (loadNew)
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 15,
                      ),
                    MessageBubble(
                      chatDocs[index].data()['createdAt'],
                      loadNew ? true : false,
                      chatDocs[index].data()['text'],
                      chatDocs[index].data()['username'],
                      chatDocs[index].data()['userImage'] ?? _defaultProfileImage,
                      chatDocs[index].data()['userId'] ==
                          user.uid, //checks wheather the message is mine or the other user.
                      key: ValueKey(
                        chatDocs[index]
                            .id, //this will ensure that flutter will efficiently re render the UI !
                      ),
                    ),
                    if (putDate)
                      Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15),
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                        child: Text(
                          putMessage,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.blueGrey,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                        ),
                      ),
                  ],
                );
              },
              itemCount: chatDocs.length,
            );
          },
        );
```

*[See the dates message that It is changing from 21 July to 19 July !]*

```html
<a href="/link/to/site">
  <img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/C2EcGHt68LEW0QAqJP/giphy.gif" />
</a>
```

this is full GIF :

- https://media.giphy.com/media/C2EcGHt68LEW0QAqJP/giphy.gif
  Sorry, as I cannot upload GIF here as it exceed the size limit :(

Here is the data I fetched from Firebase If someone needs :

```
I/flutter (14440): data for index : 0
I/flutter (14440):   on July 21, 2021 Kamini : Wow
I/flutter (14440): data for index : 1
I/flutter (14440):   on July 21, 2021 Kamini : Hi 
I/flutter (14440): data for index : 2
I/flutter (14440):   on July 21, 2021 Aayush : Hiiii
I/flutter (14440): data for index : 3
I/flutter (14440):   on July 21, 2021 Aayush : Hello
I/flutter (14440): data for index : 4
I/flutter (14440):   on July 21, 2021 Aayush : 
I/flutter (14440): data for index : 5
I/flutter (14440):   on July 21, 2021 Aayush : Hellooooo 
I/flutter (14440): data for index : 6
I/flutter (14440):   on July 21, 2021 Kamini : Hi there 
I/flutter (14440): data for index : 7
I/flutter (14440):   on July 19, 2021 Harshal : Sorry to bother you 
I/flutter (14440): data for index : 8
I/flutter (14440):   on July 19, 2021 Harshal : Okay, I understand that.
I/flutter (14440): data for index : 9
I/flutter (14440):   on July 19, 2021 Harshal : Do you mind confirming your billing address for me?
I/flutter (14440): data for index : 10
I/flutter (14440):   on July 19, 2021 Aayush : Thanks so much for being patient! We’ll be with you soon.
I/flutter (14440): data for index : 11
I/flutter (14440):   on July 19, 2021 Harshal : Yup  
I/flutter (14440): data for index : 12
I/flutter (14440):   on July 19, 2021 Aayush : Did you get it?
I/flutter (14440): data for index : 13
I/flutter (14440):   on July 19, 2021 Aayush : Welcome
I/flutter (14440): data for index : 14
I/flutter (14440):   on July 19, 2021 Harshal : Yeah, Perfect
I/flutter (14440): data for index : 15
I/flutter (14440):   on July 19, 2021 Aayush : Got it?
I/flutter (14440): data for index : 16
I/flutter (14440):   on July 19, 2021 Aayush : something like this...
I/flutter (14440): data for index : 17
I/flutter (14440):   on July 19, 2021 Aayush : I appreciate you explaining that to me. I’m going to connect you to our AayushTheApple team. I’ll let them know what you’re reaching out about. 
I/flutter (14440): data for index : 18
I/flutter (14440):   on July 19, 2021 Harshal : I can see why you’d want that! I’m sorry, but it’s not something that we currently offer right now.
I/flutter (14440): data for index : 19
I/flutter (14440):   on July 19, 2021 Harshal : I hear you. I’m sorry that you’re still having trouble with this. I’m going to talk to my team to see what else we can do here.
I/flutter (14440): data for index : 20
I/flutter (14440):   on July 19, 2021 Aayush : Nobody is perfect. There will come a time where every single customer service representative has to apologize. Apologies are more valuable than credits or discounts. They’re an essential tool in your team’s toolkits.
I/flutter (14440): data for index : 21
I/flutter (14440):   on July 19, 2021 Harshal : Do you mind if we start a co-browsing session so I can help you with this process?
I/flutter (14440): data for index : 22
I/flutter (14440):   on July 19, 2021 Harshal : Sure, why not?
I/flutter (14440): data for index : 23
I/flutter (14440):   on July 17, 2021 Aayush : I think it might be easier if we could co-browse to address your issue. We’ll need to access your screen. Is that alright?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **ListView.separated()** to do it.

The logic below might be a bit confusing, but I've tried my best to describe it :)
Please read the comments in the code.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

class Message {
  final DateTime dateSent;
  final String text;

  Message({
    required this.dateSent,
    required this.text,
  });
}

class SomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final separatorDateFormatter =
      DateFormat('dd MMM yyyy'); // Date Formatter for the separator

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // We will generate some data to work with as an example
    final messages = <Message>[];
    // Generate 10 days
    for (var day = 1; day < 11; day++) {
      final time = DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: day));
      // With 3 messages for each day
      for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        final messageTime = time.subtract(Duration(hours: i));
        messages.add(Message(
          dateSent: messageTime,
          text: 'Day $day, Message #$i, Time $messageTime',
        ));
      }
    }

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[400],
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('ListView.separated'),
      ),
      body: ListView.separated(
        // We add +1 to the actual list size so that we can build the very first separator (conversation start date)
        itemCount: messages.length + (messages.isNotEmpty ? 1 : 0),
        // Your message widget here
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          if (index == 0) {
            final firstMessage = messages.first;
            return _buildDateSeparator(firstMessage.dateSent);
          }
          final message = messages.elementAt(index - 1);
          return _messageWidget(message);
        },
        // This is the place to build the date separator
        separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
          // If index is 0, the return nothing (since we have added +1 to the count above)
          if (index == 0) return SizedBox();

          // We take current Message from the list (as usual, -1 because of increased length above)
          final currentMessage = messages.elementAt(index - 1);

          // We get the next message from the list
          // No need to check if the message might be null, since **separatorBuilder()** will not be called after the last entry of the list
          final nextMessage = messages.elementAt(index);

          // Compare it's date to the current one
          if (!_isSameDate(currentMessage, nextMessage)) {
            // Return date separator if the date doesn't match
            return _buildDateSeparator(nextMessage.dateSent);
          }

          // Return nothing otherwise
          return SizedBox();
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  // The function that compares the date between two messages
  // This code can be exported to some helper class or refactored in to an Extension for DateTime class
  bool _isSameDate(Message message1, Message message2) =>
      message1.dateSent.year == message2.dateSent.year &&
      message1.dateSent.month == message2.dateSent.month &&
      message1.dateSent.day == message2.dateSent.day;

  Widget _messageWidget(Message message) => Container(
        height: 40.0,
        color: Colors.grey,
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          vertical: 5.0,
        ),
        child: Center(
          child: Text(message.text),
        ),
      );

  Widget _buildDateSeparator(DateTime date) => Container(
        child: Center(
          child: Text(separatorDateFormatter.format(date)),
        ),
      );
}
```

Also note that **ListView.separated()** does not call **separatorBuilder()** before the first item of the List and after the last one (only between the items). So in order to display the initial date separator (conversation start date) we have to increase **itemCount** by 1 and decrease the index by 1 when we want to select the current List entry.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed solution ! I'll let you know if this works :)

Comment: Hi there! Your solution seems working but I have two doubts , first one is how to reverse the list? I know that by applying `reverse:true` but we also have to change some logic then and why I am getting the Range Error when scrolling to the end ?

Comment: Hi thanks a ton! your approach is great   btw I have to make changes as I wanted reverse Listview builder so that there were also some changes regarding index logic but Your solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're right that this is caused by ListView.builder reusing widgets. To solve this, you can give each dateSeparator a GlobalObjectKey(date). Something like this:

```
Widget _buildDateSeparator(DateTime date) => Container(
    child: Center(
    key: GlobalObjectKey(date),
      child: Text(separatorDateFormatter.format(date)),
    ),
  );
```

I haven't tested but I've had issues like that before.

Comment: Thanks for your response ! But I had already tried this but the problem still exists :(

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@Thepeanut](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9039032/thepeanut),
After applying the logic provided by him,
Here is the final working code :

```
StreamBuilder(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('chat')
          .orderBy(
            'createdAt',
            descending: true,
          ) //by default it is in accending order.
          .snapshots(), //with ordering by timestamps!
      builder: (ctx, chatSnapshot) {
        if (chatSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Center(
            child: AdaptiveCircularProgressIndicator(false),
          );
        }

        final chatDocs = chatSnapshot.data.docs;
        // print('CHATS_DATA : ${chatDocs.data()}');
        for (int i = 0; i < chatDocs.length; i++) {
          print(
              'data for index : $i\n\t on ${getDateStr(chatDocs[i].data()['createdAt'])} ${chatDocs[i].data()['username']} : ${chatDocs[i].data()['text']}');
        }

        return ListView.separated(
          reverse: true,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            // bool loadNew = false;
            bool loadNew = (index == chatDocs.length - 1) ||
                (index != chatDocs.length - 1 &&
                    chatDocs[index + 1].data()['userId'] !=
                        chatDocs[index].data()['userId']);
            if (index == chatDocs.length - 1) {
              var dateMessage = getDateStr(chatDocs[index].data()['createdAt']);
              print(
                  'index end : itembuilder. DateSepator builded. || $dateMessage');
              return Column(
                children: [
                  _buildDateSeparator(dateMessage),
                  _buildMessage(
                    chatDocs: chatDocs,
                    loadNew: loadNew,
                    index: index,
                    user: user,
                  ),
                ],
              );
            }
            print(
                'index $index : itembuilder. Message builded. || ${chatDocs[index].data()['text']}');
            return _buildMessage(
              chatDocs: chatDocs,
              loadNew: loadNew,
              index: index,
              user: user,
            );
          },
          separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
            if (index == chatDocs.length - 1) {
              print('\tno separator.');
              return SizedBox();
            }
            final currentMessageDate =
                chatDocs[index].data()['createdAt'].toDate();
            // if (index == chatDocs.length - 1) {
            //   var dateMessage =
            //       getDateStr(chatDocs[index - 1].data()['createdAt']);
            //   return _buildDateSeparator(dateMessage);
            // }
            // print('accessing overflow : $index ${chatDocs.length}');
            final nextMessageDate =
                chatDocs[index + 1].data()['createdAt'].toDate();
            if (!_isSameDate(currentMessageDate, nextMessageDate)) {
              var dateMessage = getDateStr(chatDocs[index].data()['createdAt']);
              print('\tDate separator. || $dateMessage');
              return _buildDateSeparator(dateMessage);
            }
            print('\tno separator end.');
            return SizedBox();
          },
          itemCount: chatDocs.length,
          // itemCount: chatDocs.length + (chatDocs.isNotEmpty ? 1 : 0),
        );
      },
    )
```

Additional functions :

```
Widget _buildDateSeparator(String dateMessage) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Container(
          // key: GlobalObjectKey(putMessage),
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15),
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
          child: Text(
            dateMessage,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
          constraints: BoxConstraints(),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.blueGrey,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildMessage({
    @required var chatDocs,
    @required bool loadNew,
    @required int index,
    @required var user,
  }) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        if (loadNew)
          SizedBox(
            height: 15,
          ),
        MessageBubble(
          chatDocs[index].data()['createdAt'],
          loadNew ? true : false,
          chatDocs[index].data()['text'],
          chatDocs[index].data()['username'],
          chatDocs[index].data()['userImage'] ?? _defaultProfileImage,
          chatDocs[index].data()['userId'] ==
              user.uid, //checks wheather the message is mine or the other user.
          key: ValueKey(
            chatDocs[index]
                .id, //this will ensure that flutter will efficiently re render the UI !
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  bool _isSameDate(DateTime date1, DateTime date2) {
    return date1.year == date2.year &&
        date1.month == date2.month &&
        date1.day == date2.day;
  }
```

Refer to his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68473443/14343554) for logic with needful comments!